# XPath expression to select node if it matches a specific attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to find the minimum and maximum id values in `r:waypoints/r:waypoint`.

i.e. in this case: `r:waypoint id="1"` would be the minimum and `r:waypoint id="3"` would be the maximum.

Once found, I want to select the value in `<a:place></a:place>`, but if `<a:place></a:place>` is not available, I want to select the value in `<a:street></a:street>`. Is it not possible?

**XSL**

My attempt at finding the minimum, this returns everything in the node however, and not `<a:place></a:place>` as intended.

```
<xsl:for-each select="r:rides/r:ride">
     <xsl:value-of select="//*[contains(r:waypoints/r:waypoint/@id,'1')]"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**XML**

```
<r:rides>
    <r:ride>
        <r:lead pickup="1" dropoff="2">
        </r:lead>
        <r:passenger pickup="1" dropoff="3">
        </r:passenger>
        <r:waypoints>
            <r:waypoint id="1">
                <a:place>Victory Hall</a:place>     
                <a:street></a:street>       
            </r:waypoint>
            <r:waypoint id="2">
                <a:street></a:street>           
            </r:waypoint>
            <r:waypoint id="3">
                <a:street>Harbridge Avenue</a:street>       
            </r:waypoint>
        </r:waypoints>
    </r:ride>
</r:rides>
```

**Expected Output**

```
Victory Hall to Harbridge Avenue
```

Comment: What would the expected output look like?

Comment: I've updated the question to show this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
<xsl:template match="ride">
    <xsl:for-each select="waypoints/waypoint">
        <xsl:sort select="@id" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:value-of select="(place|street)[1]" />
            <xsl:text> to </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
            <xsl:value-of select="(place|street)[1]" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Note: I have removed the prefixes because they are not bound to a namespace.

Comment: How would I select everything else in between? Or do I need another question for this?

Comment: "*How would I select everything else in between?*" Select - for what purpose? In which context?

Comment: For example,  make a selection that omits the first and last nodes

Comment: You could probably use `not(position()=1 or position()=last())`. I am not sure where you're going with this.